# flatten Options inside Spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to reproduce the behaviour of scala vanilla collections' `flatten` with `Option` on a Spark RDD. For example:

```
Seq(Some(1), None, Some(2), None, None).flatten
> Seq[Int] = List(1, 2)
// None are removed, and Some are unwrapped

sc.parallelize(Seq(Some(1), None, Some(2))).flatten.collect()
> error: value flatten is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Option[Int]]
>      sc.parallelize(Seq(Some(1), None, Some(2), None, None)).flatten.collect()
// The function does not exist for RDDs
```

Of course the following works but this means that you collect before filtering, e.g. collect a larger collection on a single machine.

```
sc.parallelize(Seq(Some(1), None, Some(2))).collect().flatten
> Array[Int] = Array(1, 2)
```

The solution I found is

```
sc.parallelize(Seq(Some(1), None, Some(2))).filter(_.isDefined).map(_.get).collect()
```

but that's not very clear. Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply perform `flatMap` with an identity function:

```
sc.parallelize(Seq(Some(1), None, Some(2))).flatMap(x => x).collect
// res1: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an Extension method on the container class to facilitate flattening and in keeping with the coding style you would like to use.

Generally one does this in Scala using implicit classes

You can also use map and pass in a function that flattens.